# asyncore.dispatcher_with_send.send() returns None

Tags: python, python-3.x, asyncore

I have the following code:

```
class Handler(asyncore.dispatcher_with_send):
    def __init__(self, class_, sock):
        super().__init__(sock)
        # ...

    # ...

    def writable(self):
        return self.generator or self._out_buffer
    def handle_write(self):
        # ...

        sent = self.send(self._out_buffer)
        import sys
        print(self._out_buffer)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        assert sent is not None
        # ...
        self._out_buffer = self._out_buffer[sent:]
        if not self._out_buffer:
            print('Closing connection.')
            self.close()

    def handle_close(self):
        print('connection closed.')
        super().handle_close()
```

Whose output is:

```
Incoming connection from ('127.0.0.1', 39045)
b'400 Bad Request\r\n\r\n'
error: uncaptured python exception, closing channel <ppp_libmodule.async_http.Handler connected 127.0.0.1:39045 at 0x7f27c9ab6d30> (<class 'AssertionError'>: [/usr/lib/python3.4/asyncore.py|write|91] [/usr/lib/python3.4/asyncore.py|handle_write_event|461] [/home/progval/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/ppp_libmodule-0.7.2-py3.4.egg/ppp_libmodule/async_http.py|handle_write|71])
connection closed.
```

As you can see, the assertion `sent is not None` fails.

However, according to [the example given for `handle_write`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/asyncore.html#asyncore.dispatcher.handle_write), `self.send()` should only return an integer.
And the socket has not been closed, since `handle_close` is called after the assertion fails.

And the client receives the data in the buffer.

Any idea of what I am doing wrong / did not understand?

Comment: if it only returns an integer how could it be None?

Comment: That's actually what I am trying to understand.

Comment: I don't see anything about an int being returned in the docs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Handler(asyncore.dispatcher_with_send):
    ...
    sent = self.send(self._out_buffer)
    assert sent is not None
```

`asyncore.dispatcher_with_send`:

```
class dispatcher_with_send(dispatcher):
    ...    
    def send(self, data):
        if self.debug:
            self.log_info('sending %s' % repr(data))
        self.out_buffer = self.out_buffer + data
        self.initiate_send()
```

`dispatcher_with_send.send` returns nothing, so your `assert` fails.

The [example](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/asyncore.html#asyncore.dispatcher.handle_write) uses `asyncore.dispatcher`, whose `send` method returns number of bytes sent.

Comment: yep, but  it returns None  not nothing

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, in Python if a function returns nothing, it implicitely returns None.

Comment: yep, that is what I just wrote.